# Streaming uploaded file to s3 using formidable

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, formidable, node-streams

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but still i couldn't able to make it work,
i am using formidable to parse incoming file, instead of storing file in memory i want to stream to s3.

My request handler looks like below.

```
profile = async (req: Request) => {
    const form = new IncomingForm();
    form.onPart = (part: Part) => {
      part.on("data", function(data){
          // here calling s3 upload for each chunk
          s3.upload({Body: data, Key: 'test.jpg'})
      })
    };

    form.parse(req);
};
```

Since i am calling `s3.upload` for each `chunk` it overrides the previous chunk of data, so how can i handle the stream to s3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that issue like follow.

```
profile = async (req: Request) => {
    const form = new IncomingForm();
    const passThrough = new PassThrough();
    const promise = s3.upload({Bucket: 'my-test-bucket', Key: 'unique.jpg', Body: 
    passThrough}).promise()
    form.onPart = (part: Part) => {
        part.on("data", function(data){
           // pass chunk to passThrough
           data.pipe(passThrough)
        })
    };

     promise.then(uploadedData => console.log(uploadedData)).catch(err => console.log(err))

     form.parse(req);
  };
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to work since data is a buffer so data.pipe will be undefined.